# R markdown output dir

Tags: r, markdown

I'm trying to run markdown (with parameters) in a `for` loop. If i don't specify the output directory it works just fine, but if I specify a different directory from the working directory I get an error on compiling.

My code is similar to this:

```
n_report<-c(1,2,3,5)

for (n in n_report){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "C:/Users/.../report.Rmd", 
                      output_dir = "//192.168.5.4/.../.../.../REPORT", #removing this line the code works
                      output_format = "pdf_document",
                      output_file = paste0("ST", n, ".pdf"),
                      params = list(n=n)
  }
```

The output pdf must be saved on an internal server, I think that the problem depends on a wrong interpretation of the firs two "//", on console I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to compile \\192.168.5.4/.../.../.../REPORT/ST1.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
```

With everything else markdown::render the path works perfectly. 
The "report.Rmd" generate an output in pdf with `kableExtra` package.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Have troubled with this problem before, my suggestion is just render the files in working directory and if need be move them later.

Comment: That's the way, I used file.copy() inside the loop